# Range.Count difference between PC and Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am downloading historical stock price data from Yahoo Finance I need a count of the number of data points that get downloaded. The data itself gets downloaded such that Row 16 is a header row and everything beginning on Row 17 is data. I would like the sheet to work on either a Mac or a PC, and therein lies the problem.

The code I use for the number of data points is:

```
Dim Cntr As Long
Cntr = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A17"), ActiveSheet.Range("A17").End(xlDown)).Count
```

On the Mac, this gives the correct number of data points.  However, on a PC I get an answer that is 1 too many, so I have to alter the line to look like this:

```
Cntr = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A17"), ActiveSheet.Range("A17").End(xlDown)).Count
Cntr = Cntr - 1
```

Does Range.Count work differently depending if you are using a Mac or PC? I suppose I could loop through the data and get a count that way but that seems wasteful. Any other suggestions?

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011 (OS X Mavericks), and Excel 2010 (64-bit Windows 7 - both via Boot Camp and Parallels 9)

Comment: Is there any content in the cell under the bottom of the range?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there shouldn't be any difference between a MAC and PC in this regard.

When I need to return the last row or column that contains data, I usually avoid using `.End(xlDown)` (or variants) because it can be unreliable when rows are hidden or when the column/row has noncontiguous data.

Instead, I generally use the [`.Find` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) for this. When I need to find the last row in my dataset, I use `.Find` like this:

```
Range("A:A").Find("*",SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Or, to find the last column:

```
Rows("1:1").Find("*",SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
```

This method will always return the last row/column whether it's hidden or not. For your application it would look like this:

```
Cntr = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A17"), ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find _ 
              ("*",SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)).Count
```

Note that this method only works assuming that there aren't any additional tables or datasets below the dataset you need to find the last row of data for. This method truly does find the *last* cell with data in the specified row/column.